# What would be the proper way to declare a visit to Canada to get around US Online Gaming laws?

Tags: visas, canada

In the recent past (and maybe currently) there are poker players within driving distance of Windsor Ontario who would cross the border to play specific online poker events.  To simplify immigration, many just declare they are visiting on tourism.

I am wondering though, what would be the proper way to declare the this trip to immigration, and would it require any special visas?  Would the answer depend on if they were considered professional players, or amateurs?

Comment: I'm pretty convinced that if you are doing this for fun, rather than to make a living, then a normal Temporary Residence Visa (Visitor Visa) is fine. I don't think it's any different from visiting the country to play at a casino or bet on horse racing, which people have been doing for years.

Comment: A VPN might be easier :-)

Comment: I think professional gamblers are classified the same as athletes under NOC-5251 and benefit from relaxed requirements for work permits, but a phone call or two might be in order. For a brief visit  of someone who has a real job, I doubt it's expected or required. Not sure of the situation regarding taxation (lotto winnings are tax free in Canada, unlike the US, but large amounts might attract more attention in some way).

Comment: P.S. Poker players are specifically [included](https://www23.statcan.gc.ca/imdb/p3VD.pl?Function=getVD&TVD=122372&CVD=122376&CPV=5251&CST=01012011&MLV=4&CLV=4) in NOC-5251.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of other feedback I feel fairly confident converting my comment to an answer.

If you are taking part in this event for fun, then a Temporary Resident Visa (Visitor Visa) is entirely appropriate for the activity. Plenty of people already come to Canada to visit casinos, or a horserace, and to gamble while they are there. They do so on a Temporary Resident Visa.

If you are a US citizen then you do not need an actual visa to enter Canada for purposes covered by the TRV. You might be asked for your purpose in entering Canada, and "tourism" will do just fine. (I would go with "pleasure" rather than "tourism", but it won't make any difference).

If you make your living playing poker then that's an entirely different matter and you will need some kind of visa that permits work.

Answer (score 1):

A US citizen physically within Canada who gambles online, at a website based outside the United States, is not violating any US state or federal law.